# Issue installing shapely Python Package

Tags: python-3.x, shapely

I am running python 3.6 on windows and am attempting to install Shapely using

```
pip install shapely==1.6b2
```

It is giving me the following errors

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Cameron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-242ae_ih\shapely\
```

I have seen the other posts about this issue and have tried:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup
easy_install -U setuptools
```

Nothing seems to work and I am not sure what to do next. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try to use the binary from this [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely). Just use `pip install {wheel file name}` to install it.

- `Shapely‑1.5.17‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` (32-bit)
- `Shapely‑1.5.17‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.wh`l (64-bit)

Hope this would make the installation easier.

Comment: @Cameron Can you give me a vote up if my answer helps to solve the question?

Comment: hello, I tried all of the above ways - including installing the wheel file manually. But I keep getting (always the same) error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\[....]`
Do you have an idea what this could be about?

Comment: @Ivo You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985465/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) or open a new question for the problem you encountered.

Comment: I've tried this already but unfortunately without success... Thank you though!

Comment: After much searching (for windows 10) this worked. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: This helped me as well. I had to download the .wh file, and I could install it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The [docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project.html#installing-shapely-1-6) also suggest a second option for installing Shapely on Windows, namely with conda by using the conda-forge channel.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error for installing `shapely-1.5.17` via `pip install shapely`, and installing this made the pip install command work thereafter:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
```

Comment: It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, you can now simply install Shapely for Windows with:

```
pip install shapely
```

(you many need `--upgrade` to get at least version 1.7.0, when binary wheels were added for Windows)