# Python: setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python

I already updated my Python 2.7.x to 3.6 and still getting this message when I try to install any package. Examples: Flask, Kivy..

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1_cikdf6\itsdangerous\

```
System Information:

Windows 10
Python 3.6.5
pip        10.0.1
setuptools 39.0.1
wheel      0.31.0
```

Command to install: `python -m pip install 'package-name'` *running in Administrator privilege*

### UPDATE

After running `pip install ez_setup` I waited for more than 30 min and it gets blinking a white space, like it's waiting finish something.

[image]

Comment: You might need to change your command to something like `python -m pip3 install 'package-name'` if you are running with multiple versions of Python

Comment: return No module named pip3

Comment: Check to see if there is another pip installed - my thinking is that you are trying to use the old `pip` command (which has its PATH mapped to the Python 2.7 version of pip) to install a Python 3.6 package

Comment: I already remove the old python folder. `where pip` returns `C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe` one pip version

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Answer (score 6):

For me, the problem was solved with updating the pip itself:

```
# X is the required Python number, e.g. 2 or 3 or 2.7 or 3.5 or 3.6, etc.
sudo pythonX -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 3):

I was confused by this problem for many times.But I found it work recently when I see the pyinstaller releases for https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases.

1. First, You would install python 3.4.4 and set the environment venv
2. Download the get-pip.py for python 3.4.4

```sh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.4/get-pip.py -O get-pip.py
```

after that you can

```sh
python get-pip.py
```

3. Installer right version for pyinstaller in 32-bits system

```
pip install pyinstaller==3.0
```

and after that you would use

```
pyinstaller [args] <name>
```

to compile your python code in 32-bits system like Windows XP

Comment: thanks this one is works also for python27  in old centos 7

Answer (score 1):

make sure it's up to date

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

make sure module ez_setup isn't missing

```
pip install ez_setup
```

then try this

```
pip install unroll
```

if it's still not working try this

```
easy_install -U setuptools
```

and then

```
pip install unroll
```

Comment: Please, I will update my question. Take a look please

Comment: I tried everything you suggested. The module I was trying to install was "pyzmail" because I'm Automating the Boring Stuff but apparently not with this module...

Comment: I tried all of these commands. Here is what I got on both "pip install unroll" commands.. Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...\...\Local\Temp\pip-install-sl6ecs5b\unroll\ I get the same error on a several other modules as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when installing suds. I solved it by first executing 'pip install client'.

Comment: What is `client` supposed to do?